# Help deciphering Gmail script

Tags: javascript, html

I was monitoring Gmail network traffic using Microsoft Network Monitor. I observed that the server sends intermittently a packet of 104 bytes. I deciphered that packet and found it contains-

```
<script>try {parent.m("[[21,[\42noop\42]\n]\n]\n")} catch(e) {}</script>
```

Can someone please help me in deciphering what this script does?

Comment: It's probably a keep-alive for the HTTP connection.

Comment: Try tracing through the Gmail JavaScript code to figure out what `parent.m` does.

Comment: @casablanca: I used Firebug and searched through the code but found nothing. Please try and confirm this.

Comment: @Jeremy: Why do we need a script for that. Can't we use TCP Keep-Alives?

Comment: @Bruce, there is a function `m`, `function m(a,b){var c=a.search(p)...`.

Comment: @rdineiu: Can you send me the link to the script. Which tool did you use btw?

Comment: @Bruce: I was thinking more or less for the application, so that it can respond with information such as a new email or chat request. I probably should have said "application" instead of "HTTP".

Comment: @Bruce, just use your browser's "view source" functionality. You will see a `<script>` tag starting with `(function...` containing a large chunk of obfuscated code. You'll find `function m` there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the server sending status updates to the client. Try sending yourself an email while monitoring and see what happens.

"NOOP" sounds like a "no operation" message, meaning basically "nothing's new".

When something does happen, it sends JSON formatted data about what happened, such as:

```
[[["v","CIzJ7EeCcMM.en.","8","d7634f09ff9e61c8","1s6nd4ek6sr8c","!ZbXmJFDN_0FrQv3hwuA5MuXHaf_vuWmWJ2VM8bIVByboryZZvtkt4ejfKk8"]
,["di",182,,,,,[]
] ...
```

Whatever that means... It's obfuscated and optimized code that updates the interface with new number of messages, new message headers, etc...